# I have three same Id's in my HTML document and how can I catch the third Id with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML document as below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div id="Caption_G" class="editor-group">
        editor-group<br />
        <div id="Caption_L" class="editor-label ">
            editor-label
        </div>
        <div id="Caption_F" class="editor-field ">
            editor-field
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Caption_G" class="editor-group">
        editor-group<br />
        <div id="Caption_L" class="editor-label ">
            editor-label
        </div>
        <div id="Caption_F" class="editor-field ">
            editor-field
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Caption_G" class="editor-group">
        editor-group<br />
        <div id="Caption_L" class="editor-label ">
            editor-label
        </div>
        <div id="Caption_F" class="editor-field ">
            editor-field
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I catch only third id="Caption_F" with CSS for giving style to this?!
Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: id's on each page must be unique.  If you want to refer to them the same use class.  can you use javascript?

Comment: This html document is given to me by another person and he told me that I must not change in the html and must give style to it by css and I found that by "body #Caption_G:nth-of-type(3) #Caption_F{background-color: red;}" I can give style directly to that part. I want to know how can I put a text inside instead of changing background-color?

Comment: if you can't change the html you are out of luck.  id's MUST BE UNIQUE.  If they are not the code will run into problems.  Tell who ever gave you the html to first check it on https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Error: Duplicate ID Caption_G.

From line 14, column 5; to line 14, column 45

/div>↩    <div id="Caption_G" class="editor-group">↩     

Error: Duplicate ID Caption_L.

From line 16, column 9; to line 16, column 50

>↩        <div id="Caption_L" class="editor-label ">↩     

Error: Duplicate ID Caption_F.

From line 19, column 9; to line 19, column 50

>↩        <div id="Caption_F" class="editor-field ">↩

Answer (score 1):

Id is supposed to be used only once. If you have multiple instances use a class. With class, you can use

```
 classname:last-child {
   //Your styling here
 }
```

For additional info, check this site:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

You can put multiple classes in one HTML tag. For example:`<div class="editor-label Caption_L></div>`

Comment: This html document is given to me by another person and he told me that I must not change in the html and must give style to it by css and I found that by "body #Caption_G:nth-of-type(3) #Caption_F{background-color: red;}" I can give style directly to that part. I want to know how can I put a text inside instead of changing background-color?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the same ID more than once. ID must be unique. It is best to use class for similar items that you have already used. With your **editor-group** class you can use :nth-child() selector.

```css
editor-group:nth-child(3){
  //your style
}
```

Comment: This html document is given to me by another person and he told me that I must not change in the html and must give style to it by css and I found that by "body #Caption_G:nth-of-type(3) #Caption_F{background-color: red;}" I can give style directly to that part. I want to know how can I put a text inside instead of changing background-color?

Answer (score 0):

First, IDs should be unique. You should edit your document accordingly.

Concerning your problem, you can use `:last-of-type`:

```
.editor-group:last-of-type {
   // apply styles here
}
```

Comment: This html document is given to me by another person and he told me that I must not change in the html and must give style to it by css and I found that by "body #Caption_G:nth-of-type(3) #Caption_F{background-color: red;}" I can give style directly to that part. I want to know how can I put a text inside instead of changing background-color?